# ImageMagick PDF Processing

Tags: imagemagick

My site imageMagick is working for .jpg, .ai, .psd, .eps an others but is not processing .pdf documents into images.

I have updated ImageMagick with my host via SSH (in case a directory folder may have been missing).

```
    if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'art_file' ][ 'name' ] ) && $_FILES[ 'art_file'
][ 'name' ] <> "" ) {

    $check_file_type = isValidFile( $_FILES[ 'art_file' ][ 'type' ] );
    if ( $check_file_type == 1 ) { //valid extension
        $target_path = DESIGN_UPLOAD;
        $ra = rand();
        $actual_file = 'artwork_' . $ra . '_' . basename( $_FILES[
'art_file' ][ 'name' ] );
        $target_path = $target_path . $actual_file;
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'art_file' ][ 'tmp_name' ],
$target_path ) ) {
            $ret_val = 1;
            $image_url = HTTP_USER_IMAGES."design_upload/" .
$actual_file;


            //fil conversion for preview
            $ufil = explode( "/", $image_url );

            if ( is_array( $ufil ) && count( $ufil ) > 0 ) {
                $ucurr_file = end( $ufil );
                $ufile_name = explode( ".", $ucurr_file );
                $new_convert_file = $ufile_name[ 0 ] . ".png";

                if ( MODE == 0 ) { //local mode
                    // for windows platform
                    $cmdsss = "convert " . $target_path . " " .
UPLOAD_DIR . "converted_files/" . $new_convert_file;
                    $output = shell_exec( $cmdsss );
                }
                else if ( MODE == 1 ) {
                    // for live
                    $cmdsss = UPLOAD_DIR . "converted_files/" .
$new_convert_file;
                    $im = new Imagick( $target_path );
                    $im->flattenImages();
                    $im->setImageFormat( 'png' );
                    $res = $im->writeImage( $cmdsss );
                }
                else {
                    $cmdsss = UPLOAD_DIR . "converted_files/" .
$new_convert_file;
                    $im = new Imagick( $target_path );
                    $im->flattenImages();
                    $im->setImageFormat( 'png' );
                    $res = $im->writeImage( $cmdsss );
                }
            }


            $form_data = array(
              'visitor_id' => $visitor_id,
              'product_id' => $_POST[ 'sel_product_id' ],
              'size' => $_POST[ 'sel_product_size' ],
              'img_name' => $actual_file,
              'svg_img_url' => $image_url,
              'png_img_url' => '',
              'created_date' => date( 'Y-m-d H', time() ),
              'ip_address' => get_ip(),
              'which_button' => '1'
            );
            $last_id = dbRowInsert( 'wp_visitor_designs', $form_data );
            $upload_file_name = $actual_file;

            $_SESSION[ 'art_data' ][ 'last_id' ] = $last_id;
            if ( $last_id > 0 ) {
                header( "location:" . $http_path . "submit_artwork/" );
            }
        }
        else {
            $ret_val = 2;
            $upload_file_name = "";
            $last_id = "";
        }
        $upload_file_blank = 0;
    }
    else {
        $upload_file_blank = 2;
    }
}
else {
    $upload_file_blank = 1;
}
}
else {
$ret_val = 0;
$upload_file_name = "";
$last_id = "";
$upload_file_blank = 0;
}
```

I get an error on line 86 - postscript delegate failed

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Line 86 states "$im = new Imagick( $target_path );"

Comment: You probably need to install `ghostscript` to process Postscript.